# A static web page generated by NUXT has a script error only when it's dynamic routing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am creating a website on Nuxt.js and experiencing a problem below.

First, I wrote nuxt.config.js as below so a headless CMS works.

```js
export default {
  target: "static",
  ssr: true,
  generate: {
    async routes() {
      const pages = await axios
        .get(
          `https://path/to/endpint`,
          {
            headers: { "XXXX-API-KEY": process.env.API_KEY },
          }
        )
        .then((res) =>
          res.data.contents.map((content) => ({
            route: `/${content.id}`,
            payload: content,
          }))
        );
      return pages;
    },
  },

　　　　//other settings omitted
```

And then I prepared a page as "/pages/_id/index.vue" and the code is like below

```html
<template>
  <div class="article">
    <p>{{ content.title }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "",
  async asyncData({ payload }) {
    if (payload) {
      return {
        content: payload,
      };
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

In this case, when I start "nuxt start" and preview that page, actually "content.title" is shown on the page successfully, but there is a console error which says "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')". (see the image)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

I feel this behavior is weird because nuxt generate should simply generate a static-transpiled files, however this error implies that a vue variable is re-evaluated on the browser...

And when I put exactly the same code on the static routing such as `pages/preview/index.vue`, this error does not occur.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: What do you see if you disable the JS? Nuxt will have the server side generated part + hydrate into an SPA, so it will indeed be "re-evaluated" on the browser. You're generating `articles/${content.id}` but trying to access `/pages/_id/index.vue`, which do you have such difference?

Comment: Thank you for your response, and sorry there was a typo, it is "pages/${content.id}" ,not "articles/${content.id}".  And I didn't really get "disable the JS". the error is not related to my original JS code.

Comment: Sorry, mistake in nuxt.config.js again... it should be just "${content.id}". Actually I am using longer path such as "/brands/xxxx/products/${content.id}" but for showing simple example I changed that part. Sorry for confusing

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by myself.

nuxt.config.js shoud be like below

```
res.data.contents.map((content) => ({
  route: `/${content.id}`,
  payload: content,
}))
```

but my code was without slash in "route"

```
res.data.contents.map((content) => ({
  route: `${content.id}`,
  payload: content,
}))
```

didn't understand the difference yet but anyway resolved....